# unable to decode ContentResolver.openInputStream(uri)

Tags: android, inputstream, android-contentresolver

I'm having trouble decoding `InputStream` returned from `contentResolver.optInputStream(uri)`

Since `Uri` is image i first tried to decode stream with `BitmapFactory.decodeStream`. Returned bitmap is null

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);//this is null
```

Then i tried something like this to see if maybe uri is not image, but resulting byte array is empty

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final byte[] b = new byte[8192];
for (int r; (r = is.read(b)) != -1;) {
    out.write(b, 0, r);
}
```

`out.toByteArray();` is empty array

Uri is in this format: `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:19`
I also tried with different uris but same problem.

**EDIT:** Code used to pick uri is this:

```
intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, null), PICK_PHOTO_REQUEST);
```

Comment: `//this is null` ? Unclear. What is null? `is` or `bitmap`?

Comment: `bitmap` is null.

Comment: Solved the problem by using `ACTION_PICK` instead of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`

Comment: Tha will open gallery directly, not Documents app

Comment: @pedja Please write an answer if you found it working, it will help others easily.